# Database on Nodester

Tags: node.js

I just deployed a sample app on nodester, I was wondering how can I use a database with nodester (MongoDB or Couch). Can anyone suggest how can I integrate a database with nodester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out this [detailed discussion on database access on Nodester](http://groups.google.com/group/nodester/browse_thread/thread/f6411ca9f2442a14/bed456381defcd41?lnk=gst&q=install%20mongodb#bed456381defcd41)